# Activity history with Rails audited gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, android-activity, history, audit

I have rails 3 application with some models, like Product and User. I'm using "audited" gem to track changes for products, it's simple and nice working.

But I want to make special page where I want to put daily activity history. I need something like Audits.all.order("created_at") for first step, but there is no such model.

Question: How can I get all audits for today for all models?

Answer (score 6):

I think you should query like `Audited::Adapters::ActiveRecord::Audit.where("created_at >= ?", Date.today)` according to the [gem structure](https://github.com/collectiveidea/audited/blob/master/lib/audited/adapters/active_record/audit.rb)

Comment: Can be shortened to: `Audited.audit_class.where("created_at >= ?", Date.today)`

Answer (score 4):

To be able to access today's audits with:

```
@audits = Audit.today
```

Create an `audit.rb` file in `app/models/` like:

```
Audit = Audited.audit_class

class Audit
  scope :today, -> do
    where("created_at >= ?", Time.zone.today.midnight).reorder(:created_at)
  end
end
```

[Audited also provides a few named scopes of its own](https://github.com/collectiveidea/audited/blob/b6843ca52ff37eb2f6787b60a5d2798c4835d89a/lib/audited/adapters/active_record/audit.rb#L24-L33) that may prove useful:

```
scope :descending,    ->{ reorder("version DESC") }
scope :creates,       ->{ where({:action => 'create'}) }
scope :updates,       ->{ where({:action => 'update'}) }
scope :destroys,      ->{ where({:action => 'destroy'}) }

scope :up_until,      ->(date_or_time){ where("created_at <= ?", date_or_time) }
scope :from_version,  ->(version){ where(['version >= ?', version]) }
scope :to_version,    ->(version){ where(['version <= ?', version]) }
scope :auditable_finder, ->(auditable_id, auditable_type){ where(auditable_id: auditable_id, auditable_type: auditable_type) }
```

Answer (score 1):

my solution is simply to extend the audit object, e.g.

```
cat lib/audit_extensions.rb
# The audit class is part of audited plugin
# we reopen here to add search functionality
require 'audited'

module AuditExtentions
  def self.included(base)
    base.send :include, InstanceMethods
    base.class_eval do
      belongs_to :search_users, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => :user_id
      scoped_search :on => :username, :complete_value => true
      scoped_search :on => :audited_changes, :rename => 'changes'
      scoped_search :on => :created_at, :complete_value => true, :rename => :time, :default_order => :desc
      scoped_search :on => :action, :complete_value => { :create => 'create', :update => 'update', :delete => 'destroy' }
      before_save :ensure_username

    end
  end

  module InstanceMethods
    private

    def ensure_username
      self.username ||= User.current.to_s rescue ""
    end

  end
end

Audit = Audited.audit_class
Audit.send(:include, AuditExtentions)
```

Comment: can someone help me with the views? i don't know how to show it in my views. i'm using rails 3.2.6 with the latest activerecord audited gem.